# Not storing date in core data

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have a text field to show the current date.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    todayDate = [NSDate date];
   NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",todayDate];
    todoItemDueDateText.text = stringDate;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Then there is a save button to store all data into a core data entity:

```
- (IBAction)save:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    //converting string to date

    NSString *dateStr = todoItemDueDateText.text;

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];



    addToDoItem.todoName = _todoItemText.text;
    addToDoItem.todoDescription = _todoDescriptionText.text;
    addToDoItem.todoDueDate = date;
    [super saveAndDismiss];

}
```

The core data object is saved and stored, but the todoDueDate attibute remains blank, no error or exception is thrown, but the todoDate attribute is nil after saving. The other attributes are perfectly stored..Any idea to this behaviour?
The date shown is from type `2014-01-14 17:25:22 +0000`

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `date` object is not nil?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Perhaps you think you're assigning a date object to your Core Data object, but you're assigning a `nil` instead. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date format doesn't match the string that you're trying to parse. Compare "yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" and "2014-01-14 17:25:22 +0000".

Your format needs to be something like

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
```